# What does $obj = new BlahBlahName($_GET); do?

Tags: php

I know that we use GET function to get the variables from the url in php when we use the GET method to pass data across pages or within the same page.

However

```
$obj = new BlahBlahName($_GET);
```

what does this do?

Comment: [`$_GET`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) is not a function, nor a method, but a [reserved variable](http://de.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php) holding an array

Comment: @Gordon - Someone needs to send the memo to w3schools: http://w3schools.com/PHP/php_get.asp

Comment: @Rob Hruska: w3schools is not completely not right. The superglobals are indeed not populated right from the start, it gets filled first when accessed. So PHP-internally it's a "function". But nevermind, this ambiguity has no place in end-user documentation.

Comment: @Karthik: Do have a link where you've seen this? (=me interested)

Comment: @mario: Actually I am working on a large website with lots of modules. So in this particular file there is this function which calls another class. I was surprised to see just $_GET being passed and did not know what it contains. I do know that we use GET to retrieve the variables from the URL. So that is the reason why I asked.

Comment: In this case I would assume the intent/purpose is actually to copy the $_GET array, so its use or modification within that submodule will not disturb the main application flow. Which is a common approach, just with a more unusual syntax here.

Comment: @all: Moral of the story is to not use w3schools as a reference all the time but also use the manual to get the fundamentals correct!

Comment: @mario do you have any links supporting that `$_GET` will be initially empty and only lazyloaded on demand?

Comment: @Gordon: [citation needed] No can't find it. But as I remember the article also suggested that this behaviour was a SAPI-specific performance feature (e.g. you wouldn't need that for _GET in mod_php, but _POST isn't deciphered by Apache/PHP initially I guess).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to understand this, you should understand what is the "$_GET" variable. To get full information about it, you can read the official PHP.net documentation on it. Here is the link: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Here is the information summarized. Basically whenever a page loads and has some variables are defined in it's address, PHP generates an array variable named $_GET. So, this variable is nothing more than an array. For example, if the page with the following address would be loaded: **www.example.com?var1=val1&var2=val2**, the $_GET array would look something like this:

```
{
    'var1' => 'val1',
    'var2' => 'val2'
}
```

So, since the $_GET is an array, you can apply different functions to it. You can check if this variable/array has been defined already isset($_GET), count how many elements are in it count($_GET), and so on. None of these function will actually have to look at the specific values of the array like $_GET["var1"], but look at the array in general.

In your example, $_GET is passed into not just any function but to a class when an instance of it is initialized. Whenever a class object is created, a certain function is called named constructor. So, this $_GET array is simply passed into this constructor function. To read more about constructors, you can go here: **http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php**.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

It simply passes the `$_GET` array to to the `BlahBlahName` [constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php). The constructor might pull whatever it needs from the array when creating the `BlahBlahName` object.

`$_GET` is not a function; rather, it is an [associative array of variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) provided in the request. <strike>*For some reason w3schools [calls it a function](http://w3schools.com/PHP/php_get.asp); this seems misleading.*</strike>*

Have a look at the actual code for the `BlahBlahName` `__construct()` function (if you can) to see exactly what it's doing with the variable if you're curious.

<sup>* W3schools has since updated their description of `$_GET`</sup>

Comment: Another reason not to use w3schools but the PHP manual or [a decent book for learning PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90924/what-is-the-best-php-programming-book)

Answer (score 0):

It creates a new BlahBlahName object using the $_GET array. The constructor probably parses the values in the array and assigns them to BlahBlahName properties.

Answer (score 0):

That calls the constructor for `BlahBlahName` with passing `$_GET` and assigns it to `$obj`.

Answer (score 0):

It would pass the array **$_GET** to the constructor of the **BlahBlahName** class. **$_GET** is an array of variables passed in the URL.

http://w3schools.com/PHP/php_get.asp

Answer (score 0):

**new BlahBlahName** will return a new instance of an object/class to the $obj variable. From this you will be able to call methods from the class, e.g. **$obj->method()**. The class in question which it will use will be **BlahBlahName**.

In your code, you are passing through the $_GET array into the classes constructor, which is essentially pointless because $_GET is a superglobal and should be available throughout your code.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely a filter object wrapping the PHP input arrays. I'm using something similar:

```
 $_REQUEST = new input($_REQUEST);
```

It basically captures the former `$_REQUEST` array and makes it an object property.
[Object-oriented superglobals](http://milki.erphesfurt.de/blog/index.php?/archives/6-Input-sanitizing-with-object-oriented-superglobals.html)